# ERROR IN GGPLOT IN R-x variable is discrete

Tags: r

[image]When executing below R code, getting error like:-

Code:-

```
ggplot(train,aes(x = Pclass,fill=factor(Survived)))+
geom_histogram(width = 0.5)+
xlab("Pclass")+
ylab("TotalCount")+
labs(fill="Survived")
```

Error:-

> Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is
>   discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

what could be possible reason ?
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: are you trying to plot a histogram?

Comment: @AK88: Yes......

Comment: what does your data look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this maybe:

```
  ggplot(train,aes(x = Pclass,fill=factor(Survived)))+
    geom_bar(width = 0.5)+
    xlab("Pclass")+
    ylab("TotalCount")+
    labs(fill="Survived")
```

Comment: Sorry: Getting Error like: Error: StatBin requires a continuous x variable the x variable is discrete. Perhaps you want stat="count"?

Comment: How about now??

Comment: Thanks a lot. may please tell me what error i was doing

Comment: Take a careful look at these two sources: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_histogram.html, http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html. I couldn't explain it more eloquently.

Comment: ok... we should used bar as we are dealing with category rather than density. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

your Pclass has a class of "factor which is discrete in nature.We want it to be continuous so convert factor to integer format

```
train.combined$Pclass<-as.integer(train$Pclass)
```

and then write your code that you wrote.this will work!